# Doctrine ORM: Can I get a count of affected rows after flushing changes?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

With the Doctrine ORM, is it possible to get a count of affected rows after calling `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::flush()`?

The goal is purely to be informative on a console command to confirm to the user how many rows in the database changed.

Comment: Because Doctrine is not specifically designed to work with `rows`, it probably does not. What do you want to do and why do you need this information so we can provide alternative solution more fitted to an `ORM`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get affected rows by calling `\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement::rowCount()`.